# Подключить библиотеку в qt

Tags: java, c++, qt, кроссплатформенность

Хочу использовать возможности библиотеки QAndroidJniObject. Чтобы ее подключить нужно в Header прописать #include  и в qmake QT += androidextras.

Все выполнил, но все равно не видит библиотеку. Подскажите как решить?

Мой файл .pro
''

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-12-15T20:16:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += androidextras


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    Jamba.java
''
```

Comment: Покажите файл pro

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите пожалуйста, что думаете?

Comment: Здесь все правильно - если библиотека установлена, то должно работать.

Comment: Перед билдом проекта запустите `Build / Run qmake` для применения изменений, и только потом `Build / All`.

Comment: Выполнил команду "Запустить qmake", и пересобирал проект несколько раз. Выдает ошибку: `unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras.`
Что это может быть? По идее эта библиотека должна быть по умолчанию установлена. Подскажите, у кого какие еще есть идеи?

Comment: С чего вдруг по-умолчанию? Запустите MaintenanceTool и проверьте